# Create flexible alias for an application

Tags: alias

I used to use Sublime Text editor, now I plan to use Atom. It would be really nice to have some alias or variable called "editor" I might use in all scripts / commands / launchers and link this alias to an app that might be changed any time later without affecting those commands.

How could I do that? Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try creating a soft link named `editor` which points to the current editor you are using. When you switch to some other editor you can simply point the soft link to your new editor.
Command to create a soft link named editor to point to Sublime text 3:

```
ln -sf subl3 editor
```

Better create this soft link in either `/usr/bin` or `/bin`, otherwise add the directory containing link to your `PATH` that it is accessible from terminal and scripts.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you :-)

Comment: just my 2-cents, but it would be to create it in `/usr/local/bin`, so that it does not interfere with system files

Answer (score 3):

The `EDITOR` and `VISUAL` variables are well-known variables commonly used for this purpose (`cron`, `sudo`, `bash`, etc. use it). Usually, `VISUAL` takes precedence over `EDITOR`. However, both are typically used in non-GUI environments. Nothing prevents either from being a GUI program, but they usually aren't.

You can usually respect the user's settings in an desktop environment by using [`xdg-open`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xdg-open). `xdg-open` relies on various desktop-environment specific tools like `gnome-open` or `kde-open` ([How does `xdg-open`do its work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/144047/how-does-xdg-open-do-its-work)).

So, in scripts, just do:

```
xdg-open /some/file 
xdg-open proto://some/uri
```

Comment: Thank you, I am gonna learn more about xdg-open, sounds handy.

Answer (score 3):

There is already a generic binary called `editor` i.e. `/usr/bin/editor` provided by the Debian alternatives system (`update-alternatives`).

This binary is actually a symbolic link to `/etc/alternatives/editor` :

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/editor 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 24 Feb  9  2015 /usr/bin/editor -> /etc/alternatives/editor
```

which in turn is a symbolic link to the actual editor select based on priority or manually :

```
$ ls -l /etc/alternatives/editor
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 18 Feb 10  2015 /etc/alternatives/editor -> /usr/bin/vim.basic
```

Now if i open a file with :

```
editor ~/.bashrc
```

this would actually do :

```
vim.basic ~/.bashrc
```

Lets change the editor :

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config editor 
There are 5 choices for the alternative editor (providing /usr/bin/editor).

  Selection    Path                Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /bin/nano            40        auto mode
  1            /bin/ed             -100       manual mode
  2            /bin/nano            40        manual mode
  3            /usr/bin/nedit       40        manual mode
* 4            /usr/bin/vim.basic   30        manual mode
  5            /usr/bin/vim.tiny    10        manual mode
```

The one with the `*` is the currently selected one, navigate to the one you like and select that by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> or directly use `update-alternatives --set` or you can set priority as you and see in the third column by `update-alternatives --install` command. To get information about something you can use `update-alternatives --query` or `update-alternatives --list` commands.

To install a new alternative use `update-alternatives --install` command. For example adding the editor `/usr/bin/foobar` to the `editor` alternative system and giving it a priority of 100 so that this would be the default now :

```
sudo update-alternatives --install editor /etc/alternatives/editor /usr/bin/foobar 100
```

Check `man update-alternatives` to get details.